# Applescript - Variable Commands Not Working When Using "Choose From List"

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a simple international store for iTunes.

```
set country to (choose from list {"US", "CA", "UK"} with prompt "What country?")

   if country = "US" then
     tell application "iTunes"
     activate   
     open location "itmss://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/switchToStoreFront?storeFrontId=143441"
end tell
end if
```

When I click US, it doesn't do anything with iTunes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if country as text = "US" then
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `choose from list` command is returning a list of the items selected from the list.  You can do the following:

```
set country to (choose from list {"US", "CA", "UK"} with prompt "What country?")

if country = {"US"} then
    tell application "iTunes"
        activate
        open location "itmss://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/switchToStoreFront?storeFrontId=143441"
    end tell
end if
```

Alternatively, you could say `if item 1 of country = "US"`.

Comment: +1 for revealing that the "choose from list" result is a list. That's the reason the poster wasn't getting what he expected. As such, out of your 2 solutions I prefer to use... if (item 1 of country) = "US" then approach.

Comment: (item 1 of country) and country as text produce the same result.